# EBS Payment integration - PHP

Tags: php, forms, integration, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate EBS payment in php

Well i have a EBS secret key, accoundID as well as username and password to login into 
https://secure.ebs.in

Basically i have downloaded PHP kit of EBS from here

https://support.ebs.in/app/index.php?/default_import/Knowledgebase/Article/View/620/29/version-3-php.

My download file includes a file named `submit.php` which `POSTs` values into EBS server, which is happening through `<form method="post">`

Now the document says

**Merchant Website will redirect the Customer to EBS Payment Page.**

After submitting my `form` with `MD5 $secure_hash` and i have enabled 
`Secure Hash validation` in `Request Preference` in my admin panel.

My form action URL will redirect to

https://secure.ebs.in/pg/ma/reporting/graph/

Should i have to get Payment Method screen where user enter credit/debit card details? Where i am i missing? what is the exact flow of EBS integration through PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the submit as a button not as an input on "pay.html" page.

Replace

`<input name="submitted" value="Submit" type="submit" />&nbsp;`

with

`<button type="submit" form="frmTransaction" value="Submit">Submit</button>`

The error is occurring because even the submit value is getting posted as an input value.